# EF ADN specification in SIM/USIM

Tags: sim-card

I am building an application to read SIM EF files. From 3G TS 31.102 I am trying to parse the EF ADN file.

According to spec for EF ADN,

1 to X  Alpha Identifier    O   X bytes

X+1 Length of BCD number/SSC contents   M   1 byte

X+2 TON and NPI M   1 byte

X+3 to X+12 Dialling Number/SSC String  M   10 bytes

X+13    Capability/Configuration Identifier M   1 byte

X+14    Extension1 Record Identifier    M   1 byte

I am not able to get the coding for -> Length of BCD number/SSC contents.
In the spec the coding is according to GSM 04.08 but I am not able to find.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good utility [class](https://gist.github.com/neuro-sys/953548) for BCD operations to test. Assuming that you are asking how to get length of BCD digits of Abbreviated Dialling Number. ADN numbers can be 3-4 digits , if they are written as BCD they would be 2 bytes long because each BCD digit is 4-bits nibble, after TON/NPI byte you should read N bytes and convert to it to decimal value

```
byte[] bcds = DecToBCDArray(211);

System.out.println("BCD is "+ Hex.toHexString(bcds));
System.out.println("BCD length is "+ bcds.length);
System.out.println("To decimal "+ BCDtoString(bcds));
```